# Fraction in any kind of in any kind of orders

Tags: c++, templates

Hi I have a homework that update function input Fraction in any types
But I don't know what I wrong :< Can you help me

```
template <class T> struct Fraction {
    T num, denom;  //num - Numerator ; demon-Denominator
};
template <class T>
void inputFraction(T a[], int &n) {
    cout << "Enter n:"; //number of Fractions
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        cout << "Enter Numerator:";
        cin >> a[i].num;
        cout << "Enter Denominator:";
        cin >> a[i].denom;
    }
}

template <class T>
int main()
{
    T a[100];
    int n;

    inputFraction(a, n);
    
}
```

It does not work . Where am I worng ?

Comment: What is your question? What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you have some way to go in understanding templates. Writing template code isn't just a matter of putting `template <class T>` in front of everything.

1. `main` cannot be a template
2. It's clear that you are trying to write code where you can have fractions of different basic types, `Fraction<int>` or `Fraction<long>` for instance. So choose the type you want in main

   ```
   int main()
   {
       Fraction<int> a[100];
       int n;

       inputFraction(a, n);  
   }
   ```

3. Now write `inputFraction` as a template function that uses `Fraction<T>` not `T` as it's parameter

   ```
   template <class T>
   void inputFraction(Fraction<T> a[], int &n) {
       ...
   }
   ```
4. The `Fraction` template that you have is fine. The errors were everywhere else.